# Given a latitude and longitude, how can i get the geoJSON data needed to create a marker with mapbox.js

Tags: mapbox

I tried like so, but it doesn't appear to give me the information i need:

```
var coder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapnamehere',{accessToken:'accesstokenhere'});
//lat/long of hawaii
coder.reverseQuery({lat : 19.896766,lon: -155.582782},function(error,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

output of above call is:

[image]

example geoJSON object i need The specific data i need is `geometry.coordinates` like in the example below, all other data is already generated.The previous developer did only Hawaii as an example, then abruptly quit the project:

```
{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-77.629394,12.033948 ]
    },
    properties: {
        title: 'Hawaii',
        'change' : '7',
        'lat' : '19.896766',
        'long': '-155.582782',
        "icon": {
            "iconSize": [43, 22],
            "iconAnchor": [50, 50],
            "popupAnchor": [0, -55],
            "className": "dot"
        }
    }
}
```

So given a latitude and longitude, how can i retrieve coordinates for the marker? I'm assuming its relative to the map but the documentation doesn't specify how to do this. I was hopeful that the `bounds` array probably contained the information i need, but i'm unsure what these values specify, since the example geoJSON object's `geometry.coordinates` values do not appear in the `bounds` array of the api response object.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. You're saying: "So given a latitude and longitude, how can i retrieve coordinates for the marker" The latitude and longitude are the coordinates?!

Comment: @iH8 are you sure? EDIT: DAMN you are right. It threw me off because the previous developer had two random numbers there for Hawaii.

Comment: Alrighty then. you can go clean your bed now ;) good luck with your project